# Delete multiple rows from multiple tables in mysql using single value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a number of mysql tables with different table structures and all they have the followings table names and fieldnames (the ones of the left are table names and on the right are field names)

I want to be able to delete the values of the rows using a single variable (example $id = somename) in a single query

```
    user  id,
    user_image  user
    user_interest  user 
    user_lang  id 
    user_login  user
    user_personal  user
    user_prefer user
    user_reviewuser
    user_role user_id
    user_translang  user
    user_translate  user
    user_web  id
```

Also, a particular userid may not be present across all tables.

I am not sure at all on how to delete them all at once. Any tips would be appreciated, i looked at a couploe of similar questions but couldn't find a proper answer.

Comment: forign key index would make this a snap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to create a [foreign key constraint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html), and specify "ON DELETE CASCADE".  You'll need this for each of your tables that has a foreign key to user.  For example,

```
ALTER TABLE user_image
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_user_image_user FOREIGN KEY (user)
    REFERENCES user(id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Comment: Thanks, Will it matter if any of those tables dont have the user in their tables ?

Comment: No. If there's nothing to delete, nothing will be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the multi-table `DELETE` syntax. You need to use a `LEFT JOIN` in case any of the related tables do not have a corresponding row.

```
DELETE user, user_image, user_interest, ...
FROM user
LEFT JOIN user_image ON user.id = user_image.user
LEFT JOIN user_interest ON user.id = user_interest.user
...
WHERE user.id = $id
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bab24/1)

However, if you relate the tables using a foreign key constraint, with `ON DELETE CASCADE`, you can just delete the row from the `user` table, and all the related rows will be deleted.

Comment: Thanks, ON DELETE CASCADE is a better option I GUESS.